# trouble integrating Facebook SDK in my iOS game

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, sprite-kit

I am a relatively new programmer and I am having trouble integrating Facebook SDK in my iOS Sprite Kit game.

So far I have read http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-facebook-login-in-swift

and

https://gist.github.com/iaserrat/4765b0f3532dfe87986e

But they are for simple UIKit apps.

I am able to integrate it inside a View Controller class. Now I have a FBLoginView which I need to pass to the Game Scene and add it as a child. Is that possible?

Comment: What exactly is your "trouble"? Without the code and error messages we can't help fix these troubles, on the other hand a complete tutorial on that subject would be too broad for SO.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I am able to integrate it inside a View Controller class. Now I have a FBLoginView which I need to pass to the Game Scene and add it as a child. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Add this delegate to your GameScene class and then call this code in your didMoveToView:

```
var fbLoginView: FBLoginView = FBLoginView(frame: CGRect(width: 100, height: 100);
fbLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "read_friendlists"];
view.addSubview(fbLoginView);
```

Comment: What is the delegate you mentioned?